# How can I configure Daily Time Window for Large Queries for my Sharepoint Online O365 subscription?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, office-365

I need to know how I can configure Daily Time Window for Large Queries for a MySite. Is there any way I could do that for all users through Office 365 Admin portal?

I Googled it and I only got the steps for SharePoint Server and nothing concrete for SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

these settings are not exposed to SharePoint Online as per MSFT policy. To change this value, you have to login on the central admin and change it but we dont have access to central admin.

You are right this is only available in the SharePoint On prem.Please check the below blog for Office 365 limitation: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SharePoint-Online-software-boundaries-and-limits-8f34ff47-b749-408b-abc0-b605e1f6d498?CorrelationId=33c0a687-ab73-47a9-81cf-3953ca45b75a&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US